# Babel syntax highlighting for React not working?

Tags: sublime-text-3, syntax-highlighting, sublime-text

I've installed the Babel package in Sublime Text 3 (I see it in Preferences -> Package Settings), but the syntax highlighting for a sample `App.js` still looks weird:
[image]
For example, I would expect the opening and closing `<Text>` tags to have the same color. Any idea why the syntax highlighting is not working as expected?

Answer (score 2):

You have installed the package, but you‘re still using the default JavaScript syntax package (see the bottom right corner)

1. You can temporarily switch the syntax by clicking on ”JavaScript“ in the status bar and select Babel. The same can be achieved using the ”Set Syntax“ command from the Command Palette.
2. You can permanently switch the syntax from the main menu `View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as…` and select Babel